# Getting the value of range slider in HTML on change with JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html, range

I need to get the value of a range slider and put it on a label using only Javascript, I try to apply the solution I've seen during my research, but it doesn't get the value, instead it gets the text "[object HTMLInputElement]" on the label. what am I doing wrong?

This is the HTML `code`:

```
<html>
<body>
  <label id="output">0</label>
  <style>
    #output {
      background-color:yellow;
      font-size: 100;
    }
    </style>
    <input type="range" id="scale" onchange="run(this)">
      <style>
      #scale {
        width: 200;
      }
        </style>
        <script src="question.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the javascript:

```
function run(run) {
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=run;
  }
```

Comment: try this => `document.getElementById('output').textContent = run.value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `textContent` instead if `value` - values are supposed to be for `inputs` and not `labels`.

Get the value like in your function => `run.value` and assign a `textContent` to `your` label. Using `innerHTML` is **not** a good practice to use since you are only adding a text in your `label` on slider change

**Working Demo:**

```js
function run(run) {
  document.getElementById('output').textContent = run.value;
}
```

```css
#output {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 100;
}

#scale {
  width: 200;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <label id="output">0</label>
  <input type="range" id="scale" onchange="run(this)">
</body>

</html>
```